# is clojure.jdbc/insert! done in batch mode or one by one?

Tags: clojure

After I use clojure.jdbc/insert!  to insert some data, it printed many "1", so I am wondering whether the insert is done in batch mode which has better performance or done one by one which is slow. We'd  better to have it run like java jdbc batch insert.

```
clojurewerkz.testcom.core=> (time (apply (partial j/insert! postgres-db  'test_clojure [:a :b :c :d :e])   (map #(process-row % constraints) (repeat 10000 row))))
"Elapsed time: 540.111482 msecs"
(1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clojure.jdbc/insert! eventually calls

```
(apply db-do-prepared db transaction? (first stmts) (rest stmts))
```

which calls `db-do-execute-prepared-statement` so it appears your answer is yes! it does them in batches.