# How to do batch jdbc/insert! and jdbc/update! using postgresql in Clojure?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I was trying to do **batch insert and update** in Clojure but I'm having some problems.

Libraries that I use are: `clojure.java.jdbc` and `postgresql`.

There are some examples on the internet but I could not make it working, I ended up getting exceptions like this:

> CompilerException java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT
>   INTO person ( data, age ) VALUES ( 'ertu', '24' ) was aborted.  Call
>   getNextException to see the cause.

or

> CompilerException clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args
>   (6) passed to: jdbc/db-do-prepared

I'm trying to pass **maps or vectors** but it does not work so far.

Could you provide some *concrete examples* that `clojure.java.jdbc/insert! and clojure.java.jdbc/update!` work?

Also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27806348/2204772) but did not understand what `(first stmts) and (rest stmts)` are.

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried? It might help diagnose what's going wrong.

Comment: Be sure to also see the Clojure Cookbook:  https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/tree/master/06_databases

Answer (score 0):

```
(require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
         '[java-jdbc.ddl :as ddl])

(jdbc/db-do-commands db-spec
  (ddl/create-table :fruit
    [:name "varchar(16)" "PRIMARY KEY"]
    [:appearance "varchar(32)"]
    [:cost :int "NOT NULL"]
    [:unit "varchar(16)"]
    [:grade :real]))
;; -> (0)


(jdbc/insert! db-spec :fruit
  nil ; column names omitted
  ["Red Delicious" "dark red" 20 "bushel" 8.2]
  ["Plantain" "mild spotting" 48 "stalk" 7.4]
  ["Kiwifruit" "fresh"  35 "crate" 9.1]
  ["Plum" "ripe" 12 "carton" 8.4])
```

Comment: maximum number of paramaters is 5 for insert! function did you even execute the code?

Comment: I think we're on different versions... e.g. https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc/blob/8a2acd9a1fafd25c8e27c33016590d8d540667d3/src/main/clojure/clojure/java/jdbc.clj#L1119

Comment: Will look at a more recent version